# Android Custom View: Is there a setup method called before onDraw that has access to Width

Tags: android, xamarin, android-view

I have some code in an overwritten `OnDraw(Canvas canvas)` method in a custom view class which is called repetitively to draw circles using a caclulated radius. The radius only needs to be calculated once, but the view width is needed for the calculation so it cannot be done in the constructor.

```
circleRadius = Width / CIRCLES_TO_FIT_AT_ONCE / 2;
canvas.DrawCircle(Width / 2 + (i - startIndex) * circleRadius * 2, Height / 2, circleRadius, paint);
```

Is there somewhere I can move the circleRadius calculation so that it is not unnecessarally recalculated on every draw call? Perhaps another method to override?

Comment: [`onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onSizeChanged(int,%20int,%20int,%20int))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Mike M.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2850651/mike-m)

```
protected override void OnSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh)
{
    // Calculate circle size
    circleRadius = w / CIRCLES_TO_FIT_AT_ONCE / 2;
}
```